# MODIS Level 1B batch process

Tags: r, remote-sensing, batch, modis, idl

I am a new MODIS Level 1B user. I have been using the MODIS Swath tool to process my images.

However, I have over 1000 images to process. I was wondering if there a script available in IDL or R (very little coding experience) where I can batch process all the images?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you are processing MODIS data?

Comment: Yes I know MODIS MRT tool provide batch processing ut every time I failed to fixed it for batch processing using the same method as discussed in documentation, so kindly if you did it than tell me how I can I fix this issue?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. What are you trying to accomplish in terms of processing?

Both MODIS MRT Swath tool and MODIS MRT tool provide the capability for batch processing: mosaicking, resampling, etc.  In the documentation for both tools there are some examples. [MODIS MRT SWATH Documentation](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/MRTSwath_Users_Manual_2.2_Dec2010.pdf)

If you need to perform additional processing, feature scaling, mask generation, QA Analysis, and etc, I personally prefer Matlab over R.

Hope this helps,

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this tutorial ([ModisDownload: an R function to download, mosaic, and reproject the MODIS images](http://r-gis.net/?q=ModisDownload)). It has a good tool to use modis products. I you need something that is not in this tutorial you can add to your question.