# Mosaicking Modis MOD13Q1 using batch file

Tags: python, openlayers-2, gdal, mosaic, idl

I have a Modis MOD13Q1 product for Pakistan, four tiles cover my complete area and I have data consisting of 14 years, after every 16-day interval.

I want to mosaic them using a batch file which will be most useful rather than manually processing one by one using MRT tool.

What are some useful methods of mosaicing which automates my whole data by running just one script for the whole data or one script for one-year data?

I am new with programming so can you provide some documents depicting how to run the script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MODIS Level 1B batch process](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48794/modis-level-1b-batch-process)

Answer (score 1):

The follwing code solved my problem to mosaic a lot of Modis images on a folder. The code get the **day of year** of the file name and mosaic the images with the same day in common. Copy this code to a python script (example: mosaic.py), put on the images folder and run. It will create the mosaic as *.vrt files wich you can convert to *.tif later. Adapt the "MOD11_L2.A2014" and ""_LST.vrt" names to your project data.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    #coding: utf-8
    from osgeo import gdal
    import glob
    for day in range(0, 32):
    day = str('%0.3d' % day)
    gdal.BuildVRT("MOD11_L2.A2014"+day+"_LST.vrt", glob.glob("MOD11_L2.A2014"+day+"*.tif"))
```