# Mosaicing rasters with GDAL package in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, mosaic, vrt

I'm new using python and I'm trying to create a Virtual Raster mosaicing 3 raster images of Landsat in a time series. So I'm trying with gdal.BuildVRT but it doesn't work? I'll show the code:

```
    from osgeo import gdal
    import os
    import glob

    #SET PATH 
    path = 'D:\Imagery\L8 OLI TIRS'
    x = len(files))/3 #IN THE FILE I HAVE 3 TILES FOR EACH DATE
    """
    example with only one date
    NDVI
    """
    #subset route:
    in_subRoute = files[0]+'-'+files[0+x]+'-'+files[0+x*2] #string, every 'files' equals to a directory of a tile.
    subRoute = in_subRoute.split('-') #to list
    Dirmosaic = "D:\Results\mosaic.vrt" 
    gdal.BuildVRT(Dirmosaic, subRoute)
```

but doesn't happen anything

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code solved my problem to mosaic a lot of MODIS images in a folder. The code get the **day of year** of the file name and mosaic the images with the same day in common. Copy this code to a python script (example: mosaic.py), put in the images folder and run. It will create the mosaic as *.vrt files which you can convert to *.tif later. Adapt the **"MOD11_L2.A2014"** and **"_LST.vrt"** names to your project data.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    #coding: utf-8
    from osgeo import gdal
    import glob
    for day in range(0, 32):
    day = str('%0.3d' % day)
    gdal.BuildVRT("MOD11_L2.A2014"+day+"_LST.vrt", glob.glob("MOD11_L2.A2014"+day+"*.tif"))
```

Comment: This was automatically flagged as a duplicate answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111799/any-solution-to-mosaic-modis-mod13q1-using-batch-file/255650#255650. Please avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: The answer work for the both questions. How I can proceed then?

Comment: Please see the meta post on this topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be in Python?  Just use the [command-line utility](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) (assuming it was installed, e.g. with osgeo4w) with something like this:

```
gdalbuildvrt "D:\Results\mosaic.vrt" "D:\Imagery\L8 OLI TIRS\*"
```